What is a Grammatical Function in LFG?
I'm new to LFG and know that grammatical functions are considered to be primitives in it. But how can one know that the thing one is dealing with is indeed a grammatical function?
I am reading Falk's 'Subjects and Universal Grammar' where he says that GF' (traditional subject) is a function of expressing the most prominent theta-role of a predicate. More broadly, there is a mapping of theta-roles to something.
Can then a grammatical function be defined as an element of the set X such that
{theta roles} → X,

and each element of this set is associated with a particular set of properties (e.g., anaphoric prominence, null pronoun, etc.)?
